# syntax to setAttribute for primitive

Tags: aframe

What is the correct syntax?

```
popscreen.setAttribute('geometry','primitive','plane');

popscreen.setAttribute('geometry','primitive:plane');
```

I can't seem to get either to work, so maybe it's something else? No primitive is applied.

Also, when I've tried this:

```
popscreen.setAttribute('geometry', { 'primitive': 'plane', width: '5', height: '5'});
```

... the height and width are set, but the primitive is not.

I'm having similar problems with text, but instead I get this error:
components:text:error TypeError: Cannot read property 'layout' of null

For this code:

```
popscreen.setAttribute('text', 'color', 'white');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure those methods are called, because those methods are working fine (live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jk095xza/5/))

Either

```
setAttribute('geometry','primitive','plane');
```

for a single attribute change, or

```
setAttribute('geometry', { 'primitive': 'plane', 'width': '5', 'height': '5'});
```

for changing multiple attributes